# Getting error during building cardboard demo in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am getting following error while building the cardboard demo app from its original link https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/download

`Assets/Cardboard/DemoScene/Teleport.cs(28,5): error CS0103: The name 'Cardboard' does not exist in the current context`

I am using Unity v5.3.2f1.

I have already tried to search net and did not find and solution to it. I haven't change the source file in anyway. Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer is outdated. Cardboard is turning into GVR and here is the updated link to github:
https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk.git

Comment: Link only answers discouraged on stackoverflow. Please include essential parts of the solution in this post.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to install the Cardboard SDK for Unity:

[Download Cardboard SDK for Unity (direct link to unitypackage )](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-unity/blob/master/CardboardSDKForUnity.unitypackage?raw=true)

After you have both imported. Then open the DemoScene:

`/Assets/Cardboard/DemoScene/DemoScene.unity`

Comment: Thanks! it compiled after importing. It's not written that i have to import both demo and SDK separately so i got confused.